# How to keep a div on the right side of the page in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm building a website, and I'm trying to get a div element to stick to the right side of the page. 
[image]
However, when my other divs, that contain blog post data/images scroll over to the next page, the div gets entered down.
[image]
How do I prevent the right side column from being entered down, while still allowing my blog post entries to scroll over?

Here is my code, what's relevant anyways. I'm sorry if this is a beginner question (it really is). I appreciate all the help I can get. 
Thanks.

```
.column {
    float:left;
}

.column.main {
    width:70%;
    min-height:1px;
}

.column.side {
    width:20%;
    min-height:1px;

}

.column.left {
    width:10%;
    background-color:012C40;
    height:85%;
    min-width:1px;
}

.column.right {
    width:10%;
    background-color:012C40;
    height:85%;
    float:right;
    min-height:1px;       
}


.postAd {
    width:19%;
    height:32%;
    float:left;
    background-color:DAEBF2;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:.5%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.postAd img {
    width:80%;
    height:80%;*/     
}



<div class="column left">
</div>
<!--middle content-->

<div class="postAd">

    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">

    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">

    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">

    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">
</div>

<!--right side content-->

<div class="column right">
</div>
```

First of all, thanks for all of the proposed solutions! However, I've tried each one, and I'm running into problems. I have a navigation bar on top of my website, and each one overwrites that bar. When I try to make adaptations, I get the same problem as before. How do I implement these without completely destroying the layout of my website?

Again, huge thanks to everyone that responded.

Comment: If you want, you can use [`position:fixed`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) in both div, and adjust the width of the main body accordingly, so that they don't overlap, althought this may pose a problem when adjusting for responsiveness

Comment: You can also use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to easily create 3 columns, and put your contents in the middle column

Comment: do you have a live page hosted somewhere? it'lll be easier for us to debug that. hmm, maybe try position: absolute on the right div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex positioning like below

```
.parent
{
 display:flex; 
}

.right
{
 flex:1; /*which is equal to 1 portion of width */
}
.left
{
flex:1; /*which is equal to 1 portion of width */
}
.center
{
 flex:8; /*which is equal to 8 portion of width */
}
```

I suggest you to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJSoEo8JSnc) video on youtube .

Answer (score 0):

There are many different methods. One of the simpler ones is to use:

> display:table-cell

I added a middle column for the example.

```css
.column {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.column.left {
    width:10%;
    background-color:#012C40;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.column.right {
    width:10%;
    background-color:#012C40;
    color:#ffffff;    
}


.postAd {
    min-width:23.5%;
    height:32%;
    background-color:#DAEBF2;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0.5%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.postAd img {
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column left">
[column left]
</div><!-- .column.left -->

<div class="column middle">
<div class="postAd">
    [image]
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
<div class="postAd">
    [image]
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
<div class="postAd">
    [image]
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
<div class="postAd">
    [image]
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
<div class="postAd">
    [image]
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>
</div><!-- .column.middle -->

<div class="column right">
[column right]
</div><!-- .column.right -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking to do

The right-left columns should be position:fixed then I just put width:150px then for the right column width:150px and I set up for the middle content margin-left: 150px and margin-right: 150px; that's all
and I used for items in the middle content to show flex-warp

this code:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
align-items: left;
justify-content: left;
```

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.column-left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #d6c4ff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.column-right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #d6c4ff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.middle-content{
    margin-left: 17%;
        margin-right: 17%;
        height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: left;
    }
.postAd {
    width:19%;
    height:32%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#DAEBF2;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:.5%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.postAd img {
    width:80%;
    height:80%;*/     
}

</style>
</head>
<body>



<!--left side content-->
<div class="column-left">
</div>

<!--middle content-->
<div class="middle-content">
<div class="postAd">

    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">

    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">

    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">
    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>Text here!</p>
</div>

<div class="postAd">
    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>New here!</p>
</div>
<div class="postAd">
    <img src="images/Sunset.JPG" alt="sunset">
    <p>New here!</p>
</div>

</div>

<!--right side content-->

<div class="column-right">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You should use position: fixed; on the right div.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Yes, But I couldn't give a comment as I don't have reputation more than 50.